# SpringBeanFacesELResolver not working with spring WebFlow

Tags: spring, jsf, nullpointerexception, spring-webflow, managed-property

I added `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` to my `faces-config.xml` but always when I am trying to inject property using `@ManagedProperty` the injection field is null.

Do you know if SpringBeanFacesELResolver  works together with Spring WebFlow?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems injecting spring beans to manage beans with @ManagedProperty, i had also SpringBeanFacesELResolver the problem was that the beans have the @Transactional annotation and this beans has no interface when i created the interface and use the interface in the manage bean the injection was done, maybe this help you but i'm not using spring webflow

Note: I want to write this as comment but i don't know why i couldn't